# Trying to set up react.js environment, not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, environment

I used a tutorial from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

got below message from command prompt when i entered "npm start" I did everything and i have node.js installed. PLEASE HELP!!

edit: wjwar is username

```
C:\Users\wjwar\Desktop\reactApp>npm start

> reactApp@1.0.0 start C:\Users\wjwar\Desktop\reactApp
> webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot

'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactApp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactApp@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\wjwar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-27T06_01_00_391Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 3 in the guide https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm uses `npm install --save` for `webpack`, `webpack-dev-server` and `webpack-cli`, which is not correct. It should be `npm install --save-dev`

```
>npm install webpack --save-dev
>npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
>npm install webpack-cli --save-dev
```

Also the guide seems to be pretty outdated, I suspect it uses webpack version 3, while currently the default version of webpack is 4. You can try to find another sample with newer setup, or stick with `create-react-app`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, Use [Create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) where you'll get the whole boilerplate set up, edit app.js to make your changes

Answer (score 0):

install webpack and webpack-dev-server globally:

1. open cmd as an administrator
2. > npm install -g webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server
3. restart cmd